# Unexpected output in substraction

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
T subtract(T x,T y)
{
   T diff;
   diff = x - y;
   return diff;
}
class Person
{
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Person&);
   private:
      string lastName;
      string firstName;
      int age;
   public:
      void setValues(string, string, int);
      Person operator-(Person);
 };
 Person g, h, i;
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Person& per)
{
   out << per.firstName << " " << per.lastName << " " << 
      per.age << " years old" << endl;
}
void Person::setValues(string last, string first, int ager)
{
   lastName = last;
   firstName = first;
   age = ager;
}
Person Person::operator-(Person p)
{
   Person temp;
   temp.lastName = "Difference";
   temp.firstName = "Age";
   temp.age = g.age - i.age;
   return temp;
}

int main()
{

   g.setValues("Mitchell", "Donald", 40);
   h.setValues("Clayton", "Rita", 35);
   i = g - h;
   cout << g << endl;
   cout << h << endl;
   cout << i << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

In this program, the function template subtracts objects from each other. However, it does not output items correctly. For example, it is supposed to output:

> Donald Mitchell 40 years old
>
> Rita Clayton 35 years old
>
> Age difference 5 years old

It currently outputs:

> Donald Mitchell 40 years old
>
> Rita Clayton 35 years old
>
> Age Difference 40 years old

How do I fix this error?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: `temp.age = g.age - i.age;`  Are you sure you mean `g` and `i` here?

Comment: Your `operator<<` doesn't return the stream. That's bad.

Answer (score 4):

Your definition of `operator-` is wrong. You are referencing `g` and `i`, not the two persons you are doing the `-` on. It should be like this:

```
Person Person::operator-(const Person& p)
{
   Person temp;
   temp.lastName = "Difference";
   temp.firstName = "Age";
   temp.age = this->age - p.age; // You can omit this->
   return temp;
}
```

This is a decent example of global variables biting you. Without global variables, the compiler would've shown this problem to you immediately.

Comment: If you're going to paste this much code; you should correct the argument to be a const reference

Comment: @UKMonkey Alternatively, you keep `p` a value and use `p` instead of `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

Your operator- function is calculating age incorrectly. It should be

```
temp.age = this->age - p.age
```